# How can I enlarge a hole in a brick wall without drilling?

Tags: brick

I currently have a small hole in my brick wall that is bringing a cable for my satellite dish into my house.

I now want to install outdoor speakers in my backyard and I would like to feed the speaker wire through this hole, however it is too small.

I'd like to make the hole a bit larger without having to do any drilling to avoid damaging the existing cable. Is there a way to chip at the hole to make it larger that won't risk splitting the brick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically you could use some device for precision grinding like Dremel with some diamond bit with an extender to make it long enough, but that's almost mission impossible to do. First, you risk damaging the existing cable. Second, doing such job in a hard material when the hole is long and narrow will take too much time and precision to be worth it.

You actually have two options. Option one is to drill another hole or maybe find some other way to lay the new cable. Option two is to disconnect the cable, remove it, drill a wider hole in place of the existing one, then install the old cable and the new one.

Comment: agreed, just drill a new hole

Comment: So I went with the 'remove the cable and drill a wider hole in place of the existing one'. It seemed like the right thing to do from the start, but I was just hoping someone could come up with a shortcut for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can make another hole in same brick at a distance from 1st hole that the structure of brick don't disturb and it still hold weight of wall.